# Count how many in range are not blank or in list

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a list of values: (Des Moines, Omaha, Minneapolis, Kansas City)

I have a bunch of rows of data that have a city on each line (1-2 cities, there are two columns, the second is rarely used).  I need to count how many times a city shows up that is NOT one of the previously mentioned four.

What is the function code I need to put in a cell to count how many times in a range something is NOT in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A2,"<>Des Moines",A1:A2,"<>Omaha",A1:A2,"<>Minneapolis",A1:A2,"<>Kansas City",A1:A2,"<>")`

Just edit `A1:A2` as necessary. That should work - there are probably a dozen ways to do this, so if not, let me know.

edit: Thanks @Jeeped for the final condition.

Answer (score 5):

Asuming you want to count all nonempty cells (also excluding `=""`) which do not contain a value from a set list, you can use this: (asumes the checked range is A1:B8 and the list of values is at E1:E4)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$1:$B$8)>0)*1)-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$8,$E$1:$E$4))
```

This formula simply count each cell which is not empty and then subtracts the count of the matches found.

If you still have any questions, just ask :)

**EDIT**:

Regarding Scott's comment: Either go with

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$1:$B$8)>0)*1,COUNTIF($E$1:$E$4,$A$1:$B$8))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$1:$B$8)>0)-COUNTIF($E$1:$E$4,$A$1:$B$8))
```

But as said: there are LOTS of ways to solve this ;)

Comment: Just following the logic here, couldn't you combine them `=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$1:$B$8)>0)*1)-(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$8,$E$1:$E$4)>0))`? Because the null string would always also be 0 on the second the only possibilities are `0 - 0`,`1 - 0`, and `1 - 1` there would never be a time where `0 - 1` exists, which would get the same result, but less typing.  Again if I follow the logic correctly.

Comment: @ScottCraner have you tried your suggestion? `COUNTIF` would only go for the first cell in `$E$1:$E$4`. pls check my edit if that is what you meant (at least, you would need to swich the list and the range to check inside the countif)

Comment: you are correct, I always turn those around and play with it till I get it right.

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball suggests this,

```
=COUNTIFS(A:B, "<>"&G2,A:B, "<>"&"Omaha",A:B, "<>"&G4,A:B, "<>"&"Kansas City",A:B, "<>")
```

[image: cities_not]

Comment: Where can I get one of your crystal balls? It is much better than my dusty one.  I'm assuming that we can't do an array with these? Something like (but obviously not): `CountIf(A:B,"<>{"Des Moines","Omaha",...}")`?

Comment: No, if you use *does not equal* with OR criteria, they will all match multiple time. When something is *Omaha*, it can still be **not** *Kansas City*, *Minneapolis* or *Des Moines*.

Comment: as long as ther'e no empty strings, it will work... but then `=COUNTA($A:$B)-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A:$B,$G$2:$G$5))` also would work... (I hate empty strings) ;)